# MongoDB integration in Vercel works locally but not in production mode

Tags: mongodb, express, vercel

I have the problem that I can use Vercel's MongoDB locally, but when I host my Express application on Vercel it doesn't work. I added MongDB Atlas and adjusted the MONGODB_URI. As said. If I start my Express Server locally and use the same MONGODB_URI as when I host the Express App on Vercel, everything works without any problems. On Vercel I get an error

> An error occurred with your deployment FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT

This is my POST endpoint:

```
export const newUser = async (req, res, next) => {

try {
const user = new User({ ...req.body.user });

//The function is called properly because I see this line in the VERCEL logs
console.log("USER BEFORE: " + user);

const savedUser = await user.save();


//However, this line will NOT run on Vercel
console.log("SAVED USER IN MONGODB: " + savedUser);

res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

res.status(200).json(savedUser);

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
};
```